# Why does a hashCode() returning zero cause List.minus() to return an empty list?

Tags: groovy, hashcode

Given class Foo with this decidedly poor hashCode() implementation:

```
class Foo {
    String name

    public int hashCode() {
        0
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false
        }

        if (!(obj instanceof Foo)) {
            return false
        }
        Foo foo = (Foo) obj
        return this.name.equals(foo.name)
    }   
}
```

Why does the following assertion fail?

```
Foo f1 = new Foo(name: 'Name 1')
Foo f2 = new Foo(name: 'Name 2')
Foo f3 = new Foo(name: 'Name 2')
assert ([f1, f2] - [f3]).size() == 1
```

The result of the `minus()` is an empty list. If I switch the hashCode() implementaion to`return name.hashCode()`, the assertion passes.  With either implementation, methods like `contains()` work as expected.

My question is **not** how to implement a better hashCode(), but why `minus()` behaves this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this would be exactly the behaviour described in the [docs for minus](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#minus%28java.util.Collection%29):

> Create a List composed of the elements of the first list minus every occurrence of elements of the given Collection.
>
> ```
> assert [1, "a", true, true, false, 5.3] - [true, 5.3] == [1, "a", false]
> ```

You remove each element, that is in the second list.  In your case remove all f3 from [f1,f2], where all are the same, hence the empty list.

The finer details are in [`DefaultGroovyMethods.minus`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/GROOVY_2_3_X/src%2Fmain%2Forg%2Fcodehaus%2Fgroovy%2Fruntime%2FDefaultGroovyMethods.java#L9031) and then in [`NumberAwareComperator`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/NumberAwareComparator.java), which uses the `hashCode`.  as you have already found, there are open tickets regarding this (https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-7158).  So under the eyes, that `hashCode` is used there, the behaviour is perfectly consistent... should it be used there?  maybe not, because there are cases, where it really gets odd (e.g. `[[x:0,y:0]]-[[x:1,y:1]]==[]`).

The case `[f1,f2]-f3` takes another route in code and therefor behaves differently.

For now my best guess would be, that you use `minus` for immutable types (like above example), where it works quite well.  Beside that, rather work with sets.

Comment: You beat me to it. :) +1

Comment: Although, this does not happen if we just do `[f1, f2] - f3`. :)

Comment: How, in this case, is `equals()` factored in?  My assumption in the equals/hashCode contract is that where objects meet the `equals()` contract, their hashCodes must be equal.  But, objects with the same hashCode are not necessarily equal.

Comment: @dmahapatro since `[[x:0,y:0]]-[[x:1,y:1]]==[]` nothing surprises me there anymore...

Comment: ..also with the usage of `coercedEquals(Object o1, Object o2)` in `DefaultGroovyMethods`.

Comment: @dmahapatro I think that is precisely where my confusion arises.. why does `[f1, f2] - f3` behave differently than `[f1, f2] - [f3]`?

Comment: Given the use of `NumberAwareComparator`, does that mean that the minus operator between two Groovy collections is only well behaved when the objects in the collections are `Comparable`?

Comment: @mwersch there is another path taken for `minus(Set, Object)`

Comment: Because it only uses `numberAwareCompare` if the Objects implement `Comparable`. And then instead use `DefaultTypeTransformation.compareEqual(o1, o2)` which gradually depends on `equals` method on the object itself. Exactly at this [LOC](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/GROOVY_2_3_X/src%2Fmain%2Forg%2Fcodehaus%2Fgroovy%2Fruntime%2Ftypehandling%2FDefaultTypeTransformation.java#L624). :)

Comment: @IanRoberts to my understanding (which might not be much).  i only use it for more or less the example from the docs (immutable types), because it gets out of hand quite quick.

Comment: Looks like https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-7158 identifies the flaw @cfrick mentions in this answer re: `NumberAwareComparator`

Comment: I think the last sentence of this answer highlights where the issue lies: a flawed `minus()` implementation that uses `hashCode()` for equality. @cfrick, could you please edit this answer to better illustrate that issue prior to my accepting it?

Answer (score -1):

The java Collections use the implementation of `hashCode/equals` to determine object equality. Your implementation of `hashCode` indicates that that `f1`, `f2`, and `f3` are all "the same". Loosely speaking:

```
[f1, f2] - [f3]
```

could be read as

> Remove from the list all objects that are the same as f3

so it removes all objects.

You seem to already be aware that this is a terrible way to implement `hashCode`, so it's really just a case of "garbage in, garbage out".